# HttpPostedFile gets null

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, httppostedfile

I have a FileUpload control and I am trying to upload an image to server with it but it fails. My view:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadImage" runat="server" />
```

And my c#:

```
try
{
    HttpPostedFile yuklenecekDosya = FileUploadImage.PostedFile;
    if (yuklenecekDosya != null)
    {
        FileInfo dosyaBilgisi = new FileInfo(yuklenecekDosya.FileName);
        string yuklemeYeri = 
            Server.MapPath("~/Images/NewUrunler/" + dosyaBilgisi);
        FileUploadImage.SaveAs(Path.Combine(yuklemeYeri));
    }
}
//some code for catch
```

It does not give any error but also it doesn't upload image. I spend hours on it and only thing I get is 'yuklenecekDosya' come as null when I debug it. Why is it null ?

Comment: Is this inside update panel by any chance? How do you submit the uploading request?

Comment: Yes ! It is in an uploadpanel. Should I remove it ?? @Andrei

Comment: Yes, update panel = ajax, and files cannot be sent via ajax request.